# how to import .xml file to database

Tags: import, winforms, windows, xml-database

hi i want to import my .xml file to sql server database in asp.net 3.5 c# for windows application.so give m rply as fast as posible.

Comment: Are you interested in saving file into xml column ?

Comment: hope you won't mind re tagging as your question states "windows application" which was confusing with previous tag "asp.net"

Answer (score 2):

this might help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005

this code snippet might be helpful

```
     DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
  reportData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(”report.xml”));

 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(”CONNECTION STRING”);
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
  sbc.DestinationTableName = “report_table”;

   //if your DB col names don’t match your XML element names 100%
  //then relate the source XML elements (1st param) with the destination DB cols
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(”campaign”, “campaign_id”);
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(”cost”, “cost_USD”);

connection.Open();
```

refer http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/135-importing-xml-into-sql-server-table-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not brilliant, but you could read an XML file into a dataset and then use a data adapter to then populate the database...that would require very few lines of code, but not something you'd really want to hold onto...more of a once off dataload.

Answer (score 0):

first u ve 2 manipulate d xml file using an xml parser, so that the elements in the xml document converts into objects that can be accessed by other applications

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you are doing that is considered to be preprocessing, I would consider using SSIS: [Import XML to SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2007/12/11/using-xml-source.aspx)